# App crashes when onResponse is called

Tags: java, android, stack-trace

I'm using volley to load JSON data.

**This is MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    //Creating a list of posts
    private List<PostItems> mPostItemsList;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device rotated and onCreate called");

        //Initializing Views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_recycler);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //Initializing the postlist
        mPostItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new PostAdapter(mPostItemsList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(this)) {
            //Caling method to get data
            getData();
        } else {
            final Context mContext;
            mContext = this;
            final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Failed to load. Please ensure you're connected to the internet and try again.");
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (!NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(mContext)) {
                        alertDialogBuilder.show();
                    } else {
                        getData();
                    }


                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();

                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.show();

        }

    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData(){

        Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
        //Showing progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading posts", false, false);

        //Creating a json request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ConfigPost.GET_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse called");
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


}
```

If the app starts and I don't rotate it, it loads & parses the JSON quite alright; but if the app starts and I rotate the device multiple times, the app crashes as soon as `onResponse` is called.

**This is the stacktrace**

```
04-03 12:46:10.493 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: Device rotated and onCreate called
04-03 12:46:10.493 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: getData called
04-03 12:46:11.234 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: Device rotated and onCreate called
04-03 12:46:11.234 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: getData called
04-03 12:46:12.675 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: Device rotated and onCreate called
04-03 12:46:12.685 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: getData called
04-03 12:46:14.096 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: Device rotated and onCreate called
04-03 12:46:14.096 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: getData called
04-03 12:46:15.278 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: Device rotated and onCreate called
04-03 12:46:15.288 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: getData called
04-03 12:46:15.448 22221-22221/com.example.poster D/MainActivity: onResponse called
04-03 12:46:15.448 22221-22221/com.example.poster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.poster, PID: 22221
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7873bab V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,174} not attached to window manager
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
                                                                         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
                                                                         at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
                                                                         at com.example.poster.MainActivity$4.onResponse(MainActivity.java:142)
                                                                         at com.example.poster.MainActivity$4.onResponse(MainActivity.java:137)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                         at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

From the stacktrace, line 142 is `progressDialog.dismiss();` and line 137 is `new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {`

Any idea what might be causing this and it's solution?

UPDATE: I was thinking of coding it so getData() gets called only when the app is created for the first time. This because, getData() gets called when activity is re-created after configuration change  (in this case, rotation). So this causes the activity to reload. Is this possible? I.e. to call getData() only the first time, the activity is created.

Comment: put your parseData code

Comment: But the stacktrace didn't make mention of parseData? Is it really needed? Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Change ` final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading posts", false, false);` to `OnCreate()`

Comment: @Kathi, if I do that, won't the progressdialog pop up every time the activity is recreated?

Comment: sorry, don't show it `\onCreate()`, just `ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);` and show it on before `OnResponse()` in your `getData()`

Comment: @Faraday, Rohit Arya answer works well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When app rotates, **`activity` is recreated**. Now you have got the instance of `ProgressDialog` `progressDialog`. So when activity rotates, old activity gets destroyed and thus this instance `progressDialog` gets destroyed.

Now, the task is running on background thread and when it returns, it couldn't find `progressDialog` as it has been destroyed and thus currently **`not attached to window manager`**(`IllegalArgumentException`).

So better check the instance `progressDialog` before accessing it `onResponse`.

Try to use `ProgressDialog` like this:

Define a global instance:
`private ProgressDialog progressDialog;`

In `getData` method:

```
private void getData(){

    Log.d(TAG, "getData called");
    //Showing progress dialog
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading posts");
    progressDialog.show();
```

In `onResponse` callback:

```
if(progressDialog!=null){
    progressDialog.hide();
}
```

`onDestroy` of activity:

```
if(progressDialog!=null) progressDialog.dismiss(); // to prevent memory leak
```

Comment: How do I do this? And pls, I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks Sir! It worked like magic! But I have a coupla questions: why didn't we call `progressDialog.dismis ()` straight from `onRespose` and forget about it in `onDestroy` ? And secondly, can't I stop `getData ()` from being called when activity is recreated after a configuration change?

Answer (score 0):

You have to only need to check is object `null` when dismiss the `progressdialog`.

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Loading posts", false, false);

 if(progressDialog!=null)
progressDialog.dismiss();
```